# Using left join to get total rows in other table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Hi I all I have two tables, `yalladb_hotel` and `yalladb_room_types` and their structure are

**yalladb_hotel**

```
   -----------------------------------------
  | id | name | address | fax | telephone |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

And **yalladb_room_types**

```
 -----------------------------
|id | hotel_id | roomtype_name | rate |
```

Now I want to get all information from hotel table and want to get total number of room types related to hotel table. I used `left join` as it is not necessary that all hotels have room types. So I used following query

```
SELECT 
      h.*, 
      count(rm.*) as total_room_types 
   FROM 
      yalladb_hotel h 
         LEFT JOIN yalladb_room_types rm 
            ON h.id=rm.hotel_id 
   LIMIT 
      0,5
```

But it is producing following error and I am totally unable to understand the error is....

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '*) as total_room_types FROM 
yalladb_hotel h LEFT JOIN yalladb_room_types rm ON h' at line 1
```

Can any one tell what is there?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using agregate function you should put every columns(except agregate column) to GROUP BY section
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Explanation:

```
Select (these columns should be in group by section), count(agr_col) 
from table
group by (here should be those columns also)
```

Comment: goddddddddddddddy. dude this what I want +1 for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Just do

COUNT(rm.id) as Total_Room_Types

Unless you have a specific classification to differentiate between, Double, Queen, King size bed rooms.

If your Hotel room "Name" is the classification of room type as described above, you should pre-query the room types first and join to that.

```
SELECT 
      h.*, 
      COALESCE( PreQuery.Name, " " ) as RoomType,
      COALESCE( PreQuery.RoomTypeCount, 0 ) as RoomTypeCount
   FROM 
      yalladb_hotel h 
         LEFT JOIN ( select rm.hotel_id,
                            rm.name,
                            count(*) as RoomTypeCount
                        from
                           yalladb_room_types rm 
                        group by 
                           rm.hotel_id,
                           rm.name ) PreQuery
            ON h.id=PreQuery.hotel_id 
   LIMIT 
      0,5
```

**EDIT CLARIFICATIONS...**

To clarify my answer.  Instead of just a count of how many rooms, you wanted them per room type.  Per your original listed structure, you had "Name" as a column which is now listed as roomType_Name per your edits.  I suspected this column to describe the type of room.  So my inner query (as opposed to an inner join) tells the query to pre-aggregate this stuff first, grouping by the criteria and let its results be known as an alias of "PreQuery" for the join condition.   THEN, back to the main hotel table LEFT joined to "PreQuery" on the hotel ID.

Since a left join will otherwise result in NULL values if no such matches are found in whatever the "OTHER" table is, COALESCE() says... Get the value from parameter 1.  If that is null, get the second value... and put that into a final query column called ... RoomType or RoomTypeCount as in this example.  So your final query will not have any "NULL" as part of the result, but at least of proper data type expected (char and numeric respectively).

Comment: I think I am unable to convey my problem. I want to get all records from hotel table and total records as num from other table. But it is retunring only single row. But I have 3 rows in hotel table

Comment: used your query but get this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 as RoomTypeCount FROM yalladb_hotel h LEFT JOIN ( selec' at line 4`

Comment: @AwaisQarni, although you accepted another, the miss was the COALESCE().  what was a double 0 at the end was a missed shift close paren...

Comment: Sir sorry if I was unable to convey my exact problem. Frankly speaking I was totally unable to understand your answer. Second the answer of nosbor solved my problem. That's why I accepted that. I will be grateful to your if please elaborate the COALESCE(). Why it is used here and what's its common functionlaity.

Comment: @AwaisQarni, see revision for clarification